# Subgroup of the centralizer

Tags: abstract-algebra

On pg.124 of Abstract Algebra by Dummit and Foote the observation is made that In any group $G$, $<\hspace{0.2mm}g \hspace{0.2mm}> \hspace{1mm} \le \hspace{1mm} C_G(g)$
I am having a difficult time proving this observation to myself. The book gives a particular example but does not provide any proof or general explanation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To make it trivial write down with words:

$$\langle g\rangle \le C_g(g)\iff \text{any power of $\,g\,$ commutes with $\;g\;$}$$

Comment: That is so simple when stated in this way. I am getting too caught up in notation. Thank you for your help!

Comment: Sometimes we all need to take a step back, try hard to think **really** simple...and carry on.